# R unname() shows no effect in result returned from vapply()

Tags: r

I am using `unname` coupled with a few other built-in functions to grab the first two-digits in a string indicating a time like so:

```
v = vapply(vec, function(x) {
  as.numeric(unname(strsplit(x, ":")[[1]][1]))
}, 1)
```

The problem is that right now this returns named output:

```
19:22 13:30 13:30 17:00 19:20 17:00 14:15 17:00 13:30 19:15 
   19    13    13    17    19    17    14    17    13    19
```

I am using this with a large-ish `data.table` so I want to do this efficiency, i.e. not have to run `unname` twice. **Why isn't `unname` having any effect above?** 
Here's what I've tried to do so far:

- swap order of `unname` and `as.numeric`

Here's what `vec` looks like:

```
> vec
 [1] "19:22" "13:30" "13:30" "17:00" "19:20" "17:00" "14:15" "17:00" "13:30" "19:15"
```

Comment: BTW, if you always want the first two characters, you can use `substring`

Comment: @alexis_laz thanks. Unfortunately the 0-9 use only 1 character not 2, so substring doesn't work alone.

Comment: You could, also, something like `as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(vec, ":", fixed = TRUE), "[[", 1L))` to avoid having `strsplit` and `as.numeric` in your `vapply` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `unname` is working, but `vapply` itself get the "final say" so to speak, and since its `USE.NAMES` defaults to `TRUE`, you are getting names. For example,

```
R> (v <- vapply(vec, function(x) {
  as.numeric(unname(strsplit(x, ":")[[1]][1]))
}, 1, USE.NAMES = FALSE))
#[1] 19 13 13 17 19 17 14 17 13 19
##
R> (v2 <- vapply(vec, function(x) {
  as.numeric(strsplit(x, ":")[[1]][1])
}, 1, USE.NAMES = FALSE))
#[1] 19 13 13 17 19 17 14 17 13 19
```

---

So you really don't even need to use `unname`, as the second example exhibits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` :

```
vec<-c("19:22", "13:30" ,"13:30" ,"17:00", "19:20", "17:00" ,"14:15", "17:00", "13:30" ,"19:15")
as.numeric(sapply(vec,function(x){strsplit(x,':')[[1]][1]}))

[1] 19 13 13 17 19 17 14 17 13 19
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I would like to use the faster vapply if possible. I should have specified that in my question.